# MySQL: Join 1 master table to 1000 sub tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem.

I have one master table of urls. The UrlId is primary key. Starting from 10000. In this table i have all urls addresses i have found. Then i have 1000 tables in a different database (so i cannot use foreign keys). They are all identical to eachother like urldata.100 up to urldata.999. (Here i store meta data etc)

Suppose i want to use the left function in a join to join each master record for instance

Id 10000 - joins to table urldata.100
Id 11034 - joins to table urldata.110

So i wanna take out the first 3 numbers from each UrlId from the master table in a massive join.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: 1000 sub tables. really?

Comment: This is a crime against structured data and databases. Yes, it can be achieved and in an incredibly ugly way.

Comment: +1000 for @N.B. comment. Short answer: You can't, MySQL has a hard limit on 61 joins in a query.

Comment: Well the data is over 100 G. Im trying to minimize table size so that they can be optimized easier.

Comment: I dont want to be a criminal. I will look for another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a REALLY REALLY bad design, as it restricts both scalability, as well as the performance of the database.

If you really want to store your meta data for different `UrlIds`, you just need to create one table. Call it `UrlMeta`, or something similar.

The structure would be `(UrlID, MetaName, MetaValue)`. This structure can store as much meta data as you want as `(MetaName, MetaValue)` pairs.

After you manage this, your queries would become extremely simple, as you only need to join 2 tables, instead of 1001!

Comment: This is the setup i have now, but after one month of scanning and updating, there is almost over 50Mb-100MB of space to reclaim on the tables. But if i try to run a optimization during this time my system gets a bottle neck. Any other suggestions then on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: It would seem to me that your system can't handle that big a database. Have you tried uploading the database to a remote host? Also, what kind of optimization queries are you running on your database?

Comment: I have a pretty good server running, but maybe i need faster processors and memory. Im just optimizing the tables themself to reclaim space that is not in use since rows have been deleted, updated or changed etc.

Comment: In that case, you can probably use timestamps to manage the changes, and if some rows have not been modified for a set amount of time, you can delete that row to reclaim space. If any rows are deleted from your master table, you can cascade those changes through triggers and delete the meta data associated with the related UrlID. I hope this helped.

Comment: If you came to the point where you optimize for space and performance, you don't create tables and name them using numbers, you use partitioning which is an in-built function of many databases - including MySQL. What you do need in terms of computing power is a fast HDD subsystem.